# Pandas series value insertion with dtype keys

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on pandas series and I found below issue.

```
import pandas as pd
dt = pd.to_datetime(['2024-02-28 10:00:08'])
s = pd.Series([1],index=dt)
s.loc['2024-02-28 10:59'] = 10
s.loc['2024-02-28 10:2:30'] = 5
s.loc['2024-02-28'] = 3
s.loc['2024-02-28 10:08:00'] = 4
print(s)
```

I am getting below output in pandas version>2

```
2024-02-24 10:00:08    3.0
2024-02-24 10:59:00    3.0
2024-02-24 10:02:30    3.0
2024-02-24 10:08:00    4.0
dtype: float64
```

But it is showing the output below as in pandas==1.0.3

```
2024-02-28 10:00:08     1
2024-02-28 10:59       10
2024-02-28 10:2:30      5
2024-02-28              3
2024-02-28 10:08:00     4
dtype: int64
```

Is it common in latest version of pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is common in the latest version of pandas. pandas version 1.0.3 is more lenient with partial string indexing, allowing you to add entries with less specific datetime strings (e.g., '2024-02-28 10:59' or '2024-02-28 10:2:30') and automatically aligning them with the existing datetime index. But as you have noticed, in later versions of pandas, the behavior has changed, and pandas is now more strict with datetime indexing, requiring more specific datetime strings for indexing. Here's an alternate solution using `pd.Timestamp` that could achieve what your pandas version 1.03 results with pandas version > 2:

```
dt = pd.to_datetime(['2024-02-28 10:00:08'])
s = pd.Series([1], index=dt)
s.loc[pd.Timestamp('2024-02-28 10:59')] = 10
s.loc[pd.Timestamp('2024-02-28 10:02:30')] = 5
s.loc[pd.Timestamp('2024-02-28')] = 3
s.loc[pd.Timestamp('2024-02-28 10:08:00')] = 4

print(s)
```

Gives an output of

```
2024-02-28 10:00:08     1
2024-02-28 10:59:00    10
2024-02-28 10:02:30     5
2024-02-28 00:00:00     3
2024-02-28 10:08:00     4
dtype: int64
```